# Prevent session from timing out in .net mvc 6

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I have used session in my .net application. But when session expires, then the page shows exceptions. I want to know, Is there any way to prevent session from timing out or any way to extend timing out of session in asp.net mvc 6?

Comment: Why do you want that? It's not just a bad idea, it's a huge security hole.  HTTP is stateless. The server doesn't know if the user closed their browser or tab. To emulate logins and sessions, web servers store a cookie in the browser and use it to look up "session" data. The session **must** expire, otherwise someone, eg a malicious script, could hijack the browser and connect to the server on behalf of the user using the session cookie

Comment: The real solution is to fix your code so it doesn't throw exceptions if the user goes away. ASP.NET itself would redirect the user to the login page if the session expired, which means there are other bugs in the application too. Why wasn't the user redirected to the login page?